# Transpose month/year matrix into columns based data

Tags: google-sheets

I have this sheet:

[image]

I want to turn it into this:

[image]...

[Here is a data sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vlsNSy0SVIXwXkRMbYOsXrQtxwqrl3P4RSH6A2Pfxnk/edit?usp=sharing) (there is 2 sheets).

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58112059/transpose-matrix-into-2-columns) here which is kinda similar, but it is in Excel with a diff format. I didn't manage to make it work.

Any help folks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sheet is view only, so i couldn't demonstrate how to do it, but this should work:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(Sheet1!A2:A&"|"&Sheet1!B1:M1&"|"&Sheet1!B2:M),"|",0,0),"where Col3 is not null"))
```

Comment: also possible you're in Europe somewhere, in which case semicolons (;) are used as parameter separators in formulas instead of commas (,) like I used so =ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(Sheet1!A2:A&"|"&Sheet1!B1:M1&"|"&Sheet1!B2:M);"|";0;0);"where Col3 is not null")) instead

Comment: I should mention that FLATTEN() is an undocumented function that I only recently discovered.  I've believe it is intended to remain "hidden" in the back end of the sheets programming, but if what I did is what you're after, there really isn't a more efficient way to do it.  If you're uncomfortable using an undocumented function, let me know and I can try to build a different kind of work around for you.